# Email's Mailbox name in php imap

Tags: php, imap, php-imap

I am creating a mail client and have many mailboxes in that now i have a list of emails and i want to show on list that to which mailbox that email belongs

Suppose:
Show  "Inbox" if email is from Inbox
Show "Some Custom Mailbox" if the email is from Custom Mailbox

Is it possible with php_imap or any workaround that?

Thanks

Comment: imap_open will only show you one mailbox at a time, so it should be pretty obvious what mailbox you're working with.

Comment: @Max you are right but i have a requirement to list all the emails from all mailboxes.Now for this reason i wan to get mailbox name of an each email so i can use it as label.

Comment: So, you're opening the mailboxes one at a time anyway.  Just attach a piece of data to each message as you download them, or keep an associative map.  So far this isn't an IMAP problem, just a "keeping a piece of data with another piece of data" problem.